# Вывод данных в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Имеется следующий PHP-код для вывода данных на страницу:

```
<?php
$interval = $_GET['interval'];
$isCorrect = is_numeric($interval);
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `visits` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $interval");
$visits = array();
if ($interval) {
    if ($isCorrect) {
        while ($visit = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $visits[] = $visit;
        }
    } else {
        exit("Недопустимый параметр!");
    }
}
;?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<h2>Статистика</h2>

<p><a href="?interval=1">За сегодня</a></p>
<p><a href="?interval=7">За последнюю неделю</a></p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Дата</td>
        <td>Уникальных посетителей</td>
        <td>Просмотров</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $visit['date'] ;?></td>
        <td><?= $visit['hosts'] ;?></td>
        <td><?= $visit['views'] ;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Однако данные не выводятся, и соответствующая строка `<table>` остается пустой. Как исправить указанный код?

Comment: Добавить цикл `foreach ($visits as $visit)`?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: А про дыры в безопасности этого скрипта в задании ничего не было?

Comment: Нет, касательно безопасности задачи не ставилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Дата</td>
        <td>Уникальных посетителей</td>
        <td>Просмотров</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($visits as $visit) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $visit['date'] ;?></td>
            <td><?= $visit['hosts'] ;?></td>
            <td><?= $visit['views'] ;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>    
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!